# Hund's Rule for Determining Term Symbol Energy Order

Tags: quantum-chemistry, orbitals, electronic-configuration

In order to determine the energy order based on J-value for term symbols we employ Hund's rule:

- In a less than $\frac12$-filled subshell **Lowest** J-value is **Lowest** energy
- In a more than $\frac12$-filled subshell **Highest** J-value is **Lowest** energy

For configurations where only one orbital is involved such as $p^5,d^3$ etc. this is easy to apply. But what about configurations where two orbitals are involved such as $p^5d^1$ or $d^9f^1$? In these cases to which orbital do we apply the less/more than $\frac 12$-filled condition?